# Tensorflow, how to store variables?

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I've just started experimenting a bit with tensorflow but I feel like I have a hard time grasping the concept, I'm currently focusing on the MNIST-dataset, but only 8000 of them as training and 2000 for testing. The little code snippet I have currently is:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, initializers
from keras.models import Model
from Dataset import Dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras import optimizers, losses
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend as K

#global variables
d = Dataset()
num_features = d.X_train.shape[1]
low_dim = 32

def autoencoder():
    w = initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05, seed=None)
    input = Input(shape=(num_features,))

    encoded = Dense(low_dim, activation='relu', kernel_initializer = w)(input)

    decoded = Dense(num_features, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer = w)(encoded)

    autoencoder = Model(input, decoded)
    adam = optimizers.Adagrad(lr=0.01, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)
    autoencoder.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='binary_crossentropy')
    autoencoder.fit(d.X_train, d.X_train,
                    epochs=50,
                    batch_size=64,
                    shuffle=True,
                    )

    encoded_imgs = autoencoder.predict(d.X_test)
    decoded_imgs = autoencoder.predict(encoded_imgs)
    #sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    #error = losses.mean_absolute_error(decoded_imgs[0], d.X_train[0])
    #print(error.eval())
    #print(decoded_imgs.shape)
    #sess.close()
    n = 20  # how many digits we will display
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 4))
    for i in range(n):
        # display original
        #sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
        error = losses.mean_absolute_error(decoded_imgs[n], d.X_test[n])
        #print(error.eval())
        #print(decoded_imgs.shape)
        #sess.close()
        ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + 1)
        plt.imshow(d.X_test[i].reshape(28, 28))
        plt.gray()
        ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

        # display reconstruction
        ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + 1 + n)
        plt.imshow(decoded_imgs[i].reshape(28, 28))
        plt.gray()
        ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    #print(error)
    plt.show()
    return error
```

What I want to do is to store the error as a list which I later can print or plot in a graph, but how do you do this efficiently with tensorflow/keras? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the errors inside a csv file by using the callback CSVLogger. This is a code snippet for this task.

```
from keras.callbacks import CSVLogger

# define callbacks
callbacks = [CSVLogger(path_csv_logger, separator=';', append=True)]

# pass callback to model.fit() oder model.fit_generator()
model.fit_generator(
    train_batch, train_steps, epochs=10, callbacks=callbacks,
    validation_data=validation_batch, validation_steps=val_steps)
```

EDIT: For storing the errors in list you can use something like this

```
# source https://keras.io/callbacks/
class LossHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.losses = []

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but if I just want to keep them in a regular list in python, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Thank you for this snippet, I have yet another question, is there a way to evaluate the model after each epoch? What I'm looking for is to be able to get the error after each epoch and not use a for-loop and recalculate all the calculations I've already done.

Comment: Hmm ... I don't understand what you mean. Do you want to evaluate the test error after each epoch? Keras gives you the training error and the validation error after each epoch. In order to get the test error for your test data set you could only let keras fit for one epoch -> evaluate test error -> load weights and run another epoch and so forth.

Comment: Well, what I want to do is to train the model with 1 epoch, evaluate the error for each and every pattern that I have, and then I want to keep training the model (one more epoch) and do the same, but I dont want to use a for-loop and redo every calculation that I've made.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `evaluate the error`? Training error? Validation error? Or test error?